# Twitter.search("query").user evaluating to Nil after deployment to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, twitter-gem

When using the Twitter gem. This works fine when I'm running it locally, but once I deploy it to Heroku, it's clear the the user object is coming back Nil.

```
<% twit_search(search_val, coeff) do |r| %>
  <p>
    <% 
      name = r.user[:screen_name] unless r.user.nil?
      profile_url = "/tweeps?name=#{name}" 
    %>
    <b><%= link_to(name.to_s, profile_url, :target => "new") %></b>: 
  </p>
<% end %>
```

All of the parts that include `name` are empty and before I included the `unless user.nil?` the page would just fail to render when I deployed to Heroky, with the logs saying something to the effect of "no method [] for NilClass"

Here's the method I'm calling.

```
def twit_search(query, coeff)    
  Twitter.search(query, :rpp => 10).each { |r| yield r }
end
```

And even stranger is that some members of r I can access just fine and are not Nil, but user is.

Answer (score 0):

Maby ratelimit? I think twitter has 150 requests from a ip to their API per hour. Maby your not the only one doing API stuff? Check `Twitter::RateLimitStatus`

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but I don't think that's the case as I worked around the issue with this: `usr = r.user.nil? ? Twitter.status(r.id).user : r.user` which is suboptimal, but worked